# user-defined generator-like object you can send into and yield from

Tags: python, generator

I would like to be able to "send" and "receive" data into
and from an object similar to how you can do so with a generator.

---

### Why

First, an explanation. It would be nice to be able to do this because I have an object type that I'll call `Obj`, whose instances must be incrementally created and distilled. I have implemented the incremental object iteration sequence as a series of generators; I did this because the object is a very "choose your own adventure" type of thing, with different paths forking depending on what came before, and each logic step can be complicated and potentially changed in the future. One part of the logic looks kind of like this (it's much more complicated):

```
# objiter module

def PartX(obj):
    # obj does not yet have attr8
    yield 'PartX'
    # obj now has attr8
    if obj.attr1 == 1:
        yield from PartY(obj)
    if obj.attr1 == 2:
        yield from PartZ(obj)

def PartY(obj):
    yield 'PartY'

def PartZ(obj):
    # obj does not yet have Z
    yield from PartZ1
    # obj now has Z
    if hasattr(obj.Z, 'zattr1'):
        yield from PartZ1
    if hasattr(obj.Z, 'zattr2'):
        yield from PartZ2
```

The object iteration sequence can be kicked off by the `start_iter` method. Each yielded string from the incremental logic is paired with a line from an input file.

There is a `Builder` class which is a descriptor; it receives data and actually makes the incremental changes to the `Obj` instance. The data is created by each line (from the input file) and label (from the incremental logic generators) using the `get_data` method.

Here is a basic representation:

```
from .objiter import PartA
from .parse import parse_line


class Obj():
    # builder is a descriptor and context manager, used below  in load_file
    builder = Builder()
    @staticmethod
    def get_data(line, label):
        '''Makes data out of a line, label pair.'''
        parse_line(line, label)
    def _start_iter(self):
        '''Kick off object incremental logic.'''
        # begin incremental logic
        yield from PartA(self)
    @classmethod
    def load_file(cls, file_lines):
        '''Construct an instance from an input file.'''
        self = Obj() # an "empty" object
        iter_logic = self._start_iter()
        # start object creation
        with self.builder as obj_builder:
            for line, label in zip(lines, iter_logic):
                data = obj.get_data(line, label)
                obj_builder.send(data, label)
        # object creation complete
```

### What I would like to do

It would be nice to be able to simply *inject data directly* into- and receive data from- the object instance rather than using the `builder` descriptor instance. My preferred solution would allow me to write code like this (see last couple of lines):

```
            for line, label in zip(lines, iter_logic):
                data = obj.get_data(line, label)
                self.send(data, label)
                more_data = next(self)
```

I could do something like the following:

```
    def send(self, data, label):
        self.handle_data(data, label)
    def __next__(self):
        return <some_data>
```

However, this doesn't allow the desired behavior, which is to stay inside of a logic sequence and pass control back to the code calling the object's `next` or `send` methods.

### What I've tried

Right now, these are both illegal:

```
class C(FunctionType): pass
class C(GeneratorType): pass
```

So you can't make "generator-like" objects. I have considered a context manager which returns a generator, like so:

```
    def generate_me(self):
        '''The logic of handling commands and data.'''
        while True:
            command = yield
            <handle the command by sending/receiving data>
    def __enter__(self):
        self.generator = self.generate_me()
        return self.generator
    def __exit__(self, owner, value, tb):
        self.generator.close()
        del self.generator
```

Then I can do:

```
obj = Obj()
with obj as obj_gen:
    obj_gen.send(data)
    data = next(obj_gen)
```

This is all well and good, but it's still just a way of creating a separate generator with a little bit nicer syntax.

Is there a way to get real, actual generator behavior working in a user-defined object?

Comment: This looks way overcomplicated. Why is a `staticmethod` being called on an instance? Why can’t the builder be folded into `Obj` without any `__next__` shenanigans? Can `PartX` set the attributes itself?

Comment: @Ryan Having each `Part` set attributes would lead to lots of code redundancy (object iteration order is not just a Thing during creation). The static method might be overridden and/or delegated to in child classes, so it gets called. Folding builder into the class would lead to a massive class definition module (the `Part` logic is ~400 lines across 7 modules, the builder logic-which I'm still implementing-  is probably going to be around 150 lines across 2 modules, maybe three). In short: I'm trying to keep things as simple as simple as possible while keeping logic separate from structure.

Comment: @Ryan but you're right: it's totally complicated. It's my first time really making use of the idea of generators acting as mini i/o machines so it's possible I've gone a little overboard with the idea, but the problem (creating a simple API for writing, reading, and manipulation of a complex FORTRAN data structure that I have no control over) seems to justify it. Could easily be wrong. I'm not a professional developer.

Comment: Re: “object iteration order is not just a Thing during creation”: if the format is complicated enough that it needs arbitrary Python code to read it, it’s going to need arbitrary Python code to write it or whatever else (i.e. implement a serializer and deserializer). If you can find a restricted way of defining the structure that a generic de/serializer can use, that’s the other option. But I don’t see how creating a custom generator type would make the first part shorter.

Comment: @Ryan I understand - in fact I wrote a totally separate text file read/write package to handle the text (I put it on pypi for the hell of it- called it `parmatter`; relies heavily on the `parse` module) so to focus on the logic. I have not looked at any existing serializers, but I'd need to bridge between an existing serializer and the actual file format anyway. There is also the issue of manipulating the object using a piece of the serialization- ie, one character of one input file line changes "mid stream". My thought was that injecting data into the object "mid stream" makes things easier.

Comment: @Ryan I suppose you're right though- whatever object the generator logic resides in, it is going to be about the same length. In the past I have just had a hard time remembering my own APIs, and an API that isn't obvious isn't a good API. This idea of just injecting the data directly into the object seemed like an obvious thing and easy for me to understand 6-12 months from now when the object specification is modified.

Comment: And btw: `_start_iter` above is simplified; the real one receives an argument so iteration can begin at any point in the logic; by default it starts at the beginning.